# Weird SQL Server behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server

What´s the name of the behavior in the statement below?

```
Create table dbo.Foo(name varchar(10))

insert dbo.Foo (name)
select 'Weird'
union
select 'SQL'
union
select 'Server'
union
select 'behavior'

declare @title varchar(max)
set @title = ''
select @title = name + ' ' + @title from dbo.Foo

select @title

--returns 'Weird SQL Server behavior'
```

This can also be done with integers.  I want to know the name for this behavior, that mix scalar and set operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is weird about this?  You select 4 rows, SQL Server runs:

```
 @title = name + ' ' + @title
```

Four times, and you end up with the string you mention.

Kinda lucky too, since the ordering is really random.

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

> What´s the name of the behavior in the statement below?

I would call that a **side effect** from evaluating an expression for each row of a query.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the methods used sometimes to aggregate strings in SQL, see [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#_Toc205129494). Is no recommended because it relies on order of execution. On a real table ou can get 'Weird SQL Behavior' but also 'Behavior Weird Server SQL'. The problem is documented in [PRB: Execution Plan and Results of Aggregate Concatenation Queries Depend Upon Expression Location](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/287515).

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned that `SELECT @title = name FROM dbo.Foo` is the *easier* way to pick a value from a table and put it in a variable inside a SQL BATCH.

So, `select @title = name + ' ' + @title from dbo.Foo` picks the value of each row in dbo.Foo and add it in the end of `@title`.